# When receiving a new request, issue a ringtone only 1 time with Jquery, PHP and Mysql

Tags: jquery

I have an order system from which I want each new order to sound a sound for the administrator but give it only 1 ring, but it doesn't play. For this, I'm doing it as below, but I'm not getting it:

```
<audio id="notificacao" preload="auto">
  <source src="alerta.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
    
$(function() {
  function toque() {
    $.get("atualizar.php", function(result) {
      if (result == 1) {
        $('#notificacao').trigger('play');
      }
    });
  }
  let counter = 0;
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (counter == 5) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
    toque();
    counter++;
  }, 1000);
});
```

*PHP*

```
  $sql = mysqli_query($c,"SELECT * FROM pd_cart
                                    WHERE cart_status = 'P';");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
        echo 1;    
    }else{
        echo 0;
    }
```

I thought about changing `cart_status`, but I believe this can be solved in jquery. How can I resolve this?

Comment: What problem are you having? No rings or too many rings?

Comment: Hello Barmar. Forgot to include the problem in the post. I made the adjustment. No rings.

Comment: Make sure the PHP script isn't echoing anything else. Use `console.log(result)` to see the full value.